# Getting the GridColor property from a DataGridView from within the derived cell object

Tags: c#, datagridview

Now that I have converted my code into a custom `DataGridView` **Column** and **Cell**, I have a property that is not available in the **Paint** event:

```
class DataGridViewColourComboBoxCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        //base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        Rectangle rDraw;

        rDraw = Rectangle.FromLTRB(cellBounds.Left, cellBounds.Top, cellBounds.Right, cellBounds.Bottom - 1);

        //Pen penGridlines = new Pen(dataGridView.GridColor);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rDraw);
        //penGridlines.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I was using the `CellPainting` event in the DVG I was able to use:

```
    Pen penGridlines = new Pen(dataGridView.GridColor);
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rDraw);
    penGridlines.Dispose();
```

But I can't work out how to gain access to the `DataGridView` object so that I can get the `GridColor` property value.

Update:

I found on here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.gridcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx that the default colour for grid lines is `SystemColors.ControlDarkDark`. So I now have:

```
Pen penGridlines = new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDarkDark); // dataGridView.GridColor
graphics.DrawRectangle(penGridlines, rDraw);
graphics.FillRectangle(brBack, rDraw);
penGridlines.Dispose();
```

But could we use the `GridColor` property though in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the grid color like this inside paint method :
this.DataGridView.GridColor

You can then use it like.
Pen penGridlines = new Pen(this.DataGridView.GridColor);

Comment: Even though I am inside the Cell object? The DVG is in the Form.

Comment: Yes, "this.DataGridView" will give you the DataGridview where this cell belong to. Here "this" refers to the cell object only.

Comment: Yup, Please mark it as Answer if it solves your problem statement.